# how to access method of another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm making a call to a function from another view controller, but while runtime the app crushes because of 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

those are the functions as they declared at the h file:

```
@interface ValidationResultAlertView 
-(NSString*)getWarnings;
-(NSString*)getErros;
@end
```

those methods are implemented in the m file using other data members on the class.

and this  the usage at mapViewController , alertView is the instance of the previous view controller.

```
NSString * erros =  alertView.getErros;
NSString * warnings = alertView.getWarnings;*
```

there is not compilation errors.

```
ValidationResultAlertView *alertView = [[ValidationResultAlertView alloc] initWithValidationResult:result.validationResult :self];

-(NSString*)getWarnings{
    NSString * res = @"";
    for (NSString * str in _warningMessages){
        res = [ str stringByAppendingString:res];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the exception message, but unrecognised selector means that the object you have isn't what you think it is.  Lots of things will compile but not work at runtime in Objective-C - It is C.

Comment: Please update your answer, show the code in your MapViewController, show how you init ValidationResultAlertView

Comment: ValidationResultAlertView *alertView = [[ValidationResultAlertView alloc] initWithValidationResult:result.validationResult :self];

Comment: -(NSString*)getWarnings{
    NSString * res = @"";
    for (NSString * str in _warningMessages){
       res = [ str stringByAppendingString:res];
    }
    return res;
}

Comment: Try block syntax `NSString *erros = [alertView getErros];`